# Sending a web request from Android and to retrieve back response from web application

Tags: android, eclipse, webrequest

I would like to seek help in sending web request.

In part 1, I have to detect for certain text/code in sms, that is done.

Now I would like to know when the text/code (string) is being detected, how does android sends a web request over to a java web application?

Do I need to use the post and get method?

Using: Eclipse Indigo 2.7, API 2.3.3

Advices and any help would be appreciated =)

Below are my existing codes:

```
// ---get the SMS message passed in---
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
String str = "";

 if (bundle != null) // if contains message
 {

 // ---retrieve the SMS message received---
 Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
 msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
 for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)

   {
    msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
    str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
    str += " :";
          str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
    str += "\n";

   Log.i(TAG, "Message: "+msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString()); //The message content


    // Checking for Pattern
    // Direct use of Pattern:
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("123");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString());


    while (m.find()) // Find each match in turn; String can't do this.
          { 
             String result = m.group(); // Access a submatch group;
             Log.i(TAG, "Password Match: " + result);   //Showing the result
             str +="found";
          }
           } 

 // ---display the new SMS message---
 Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I cant find any url to which you want to post this string. However you can try something like WebView wv;
wv.loadUrl("http://www.abc.com?action="+str);

This will load the url as well pass the string to the web link. If it returning any response like "successful",then it will be displayed on the screen. You can also use HttpConnection for GET and POST.

Comment: I would probably want to use the GET and POST method, are there any examples that can help me to understand more so that I would know how to implement that method into my codes?

Comment: HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.example.com");  
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("account", "login"));  
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", "email@email.com));  
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
 Try the above code